# How to add shortcut keys to jqgrid pager in top toolbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Pager is defined as

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        toppager: true,
        viewrecords: false,
        recordpos: 'center',
        pagerpos: 'right',
        rowList: [500,2000],
        rowNum: 500,
        multiselect: true,
  ...
```

jqgrid top toolbar is used. Grid id is grid.
jqgrid pager does not allow to use keyboard keys.

How to add shortcut keys like (those are best unused key combinations which I have found):

```
Shift+Ctrl+Home:  First page
Ctrl+Page Up: Previous page
Ctrl+Page Down: Next page
Shift+Ctrl+End:  Last page
```

Probably something like

```
$("#BUTTONID_grid_top").click(); 
return false;
```

can used in body keydown event. But I dont know which BUTTONID ids to use.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager

does not contain pager button ids.

How to add shortcuts for top tolbar pager buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help you.
I have used jQuery hot keys plugin(jquery.hotkeys.js) to implement

Found the selector for the add icon in jqGrid Pager ( **td#add_itemsGrid.ui-pg-button** )

Then added below code to java script .

```
//Bind keyboard short cut alt+i with function addItems()
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+i',function (evt){addItems(); return 
false; });

//Function to invoke the add popup
function addItems(){
document.querySelector("td#add_itemsGrid.ui-pg-button").click();
}
```